# Trouble with a loop condition - end of file

Tags: c

Current code iteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 60
#define MAX_LIST_SIZE 15
#define MAX_QUIZ_SIZE 10

typedef struct question {
    char *question;
    char **choices;
    int n_choices;
    char *correct_answer;
} QUESTION;

char *dupString(const char *s) {
    // copies a string
    // CHECK TO SEE IF DUP WORKS

    char *dup = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (strcpy(dup, s)) {
        return dup;
    } else {
        printf("Error duplicating string");
        return 0;
    }
}

void free_question(QUESTION *q) {
    // free memory
    for(int i = 0; i < q->n_choices; i++) {
        free(q->choices[i]);
    }
    free(q->choices);
    free(q->question);
    free(q->correct_answer);

    // set pointers to null
    for(int i = 0; i < q->n_choices; i++) {
       q->choices[i] = NULL;
    }
    q->choices = NULL;
    q->question = NULL;
    q->correct_answer = NULL;
}

static int read_info(FILE *pData, char **ptr)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
        (*ptr = dupString(line)) == 0)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}

static int read_number(FILE *pData, int *num, QUESTION *q)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
        (*num = atoi(line)) < 2 || q->n_choices > 9)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}

static int read_choices(FILE *pData, QUESTION *q)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < q->n_choices; i++)
    {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
            (q->choices[i] = dupString(line)) == 0)
            return EOF;
    }
    return 0;
}

int parseQuestion(FILE *pData, int qnum, QUESTION *q)
{
    *q = (QUESTION){ NULL, NULL, 0, NULL };

    if (read_info(pData, &q->question) == EOF ||
        read_number(pData, &q->n_choices, q) == EOF ||
        (q->choices = calloc(q->n_choices, sizeof(char *))) == 0 ||
        read_choices(pData, q) == EOF ||
        read_info(pData, &q->correct_answer) == EOF)
    {
        
        return EOF;
    }

    return 0;
}

struct question makeQuestion(FILE *pData, QUESTION *q) {

    int qIndex, numChoices; 
    char question[MAX_LINE_SIZE], temp[MAX_LINE_SIZE], choices[MAX_LINE_SIZE], correctAns[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    // Eat first line = QUESTION
    fgets(question, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
    q->question = dupString(question);
    

    // Eat second line = NUMBER OF CHOICES
    fgets(temp, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
    numChoices = atoi(temp);
    q->n_choices = numChoices;

    // Allocate memory
    q->choices = calloc(q->n_choices, sizeof(char*));

    // Eat nth lines = CHOICES
    for (qIndex=0; qIndex<=numChoices-1; qIndex++) {
        fgets(choices, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
        q->choices[qIndex] = dupString(choices);
    }
    
    // Eat nth + 1 line = CORRECT ANSWER
    fgets(correctAns, MAX_LINE_SIZE, pData);
    q->correct_answer = dupString(correctAns);

    return *q;  
}           

int ask(QUESTION *q) {
    // Return 1 for correct guess, 0 for incorrect guess.
    
    int choice;

    printf("\n%s\n", q->question);

    for (int i = 0; i <= q->n_choices-1; i++) {
        printf("%d : %s", i+1, q->choices[i]);
    }

    do {
        printf("Select an answer [1-%d]: ", q->n_choices);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        
        if (choice == 0) {
            return 2;
        }

        /* Check guess */
        int ret;
        size_t size = sizeof(q->correct_answer);
        ret = memcmp(q->choices[choice-1], q->correct_answer, size);
    
        if (ret == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    } while (choice < 1 || choice > q->n_choices);

    return 0;
}


int main() {

    int num = 0;        // question being asked
    int score = 0;  // incorrect guesses
    char temp[MAX_LINE_SIZE]; // temp for loop condition

    FILE* pData;

    char *filename = "tickle.txt";
    char c;

    if ((pData = fopen(filename, "r"))) {

        printf("Welcome to the 2014 Quiz-festival!\n\n");
        printf("Are you ready to begin? [Y/y]:  ");
        c = getchar();

        if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {

            QUESTION q;
            while (parseQuestion(pData, ++num, &q) == 0) {
                makeQuestion(pData, &q);
                
                if (ask(&q) == 1) {
                    ++score;
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Oops, bad luck!\n");
                }
                free_choices(&q);
            }       

        } else {
            printf("Come back again.\n");
            return 0;
        }

    } else {
        printf("File failed to open.");
        return 0;
    }

    fclose(pData);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to be working, however, it starts at the second quiz. Now I'm just totally confused.

Example data file:

> Question 1
>
> 3 (number of answers)
>
> Answer 1a
>
> Answer 1b
>
> Answer 1c
>
> Answer 1a (this is the correct answer)
>
> Question 2
>
> 2
>
> Answer 2a
>
> Answer 2b
>
> Answer 2b (this is the correct answer)

The program starts at Question 2. Is there something going on with the memory? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: You're right that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: Reassuring, but I'm still stuck!

My code is 95% complete and this is the major roadblock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `parseQuestion()` function is the one that would detect the EOF, it should return a value that indicates whether there's a question to process (assuming EOF if there isn't).

Given that's the case, I'd probably rewrite its interface quite a bit:

```
QUESTION question;
while (parseQuestion(pData, ++num, &question) == 0)
{
    …process a known-to-be-valid question…
}
```

I'd let it do the prompt, passing the file pointer, the question number, and a pointer to a question structure which it would fill in.  It would return 0 on success and some other value (perhaps EOF) on failure.

This is more or less the standard way to deal with such issues in C.  Taking a step back, that's how you check that `fgets()` works:

```
char line[4096];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
{
    …process line…
}
```

---

You might rewrite `parseQuestion()` like this:

```
int parseQuestion(FILE *pData, int qnum, QUESTION *q)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];

    *q = (QUESTION){ NULL, NULL, 0, NULL };

    printf("******** Question: %d ********\n", num);

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
        (q->question = dupString(line)) == 0)
        return EOF;

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0)
    {
        free_choices(q);
        return EOF;
    }
    q->n_choices = atoi(line);
    if (q->n_choices < 2 || q->n_choices > 9)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of choices %d (should be 2..9)\n",
                q->n_choices);
        free_choices(q);
        return EOF;
    }

    q->choices = calloc(q->n_choices, sizeof(char *));
    if (q->choices == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed)\n");
        free_choices(q);
        return EOF;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < q->n_choices; i++)
    {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
            (q->choices[i] = dupString(line)) == 0)
        {
            free_choices(q);
            return EOF;
        }
    }

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
        (q->correct_answer = dupString(line)) == 0)
    {
        free_choices(q);
        return EOF;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, there's a lot of repetition in that code in the error handling; you might prefer to try and get rid of some of it.  You could call `free_choices()` before the first `return EOF;`, but it would have nothing to do (but the marginal performance overhead doesn't matter when you're dealing with an error).  Using `calloc()` to allocate the array of pointers is important; it means you can safely call `free_choices()` when the array is partially filled.  Such observations lead to:

```
static int read_info(FILE *pData, char **ptr)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
        (*ptr = dupString(line)) == 0)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}

static int read_number(FILE *pData, int *num)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
        (*num = atoi(line)) < 2 || q->n_choices > 9)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}

static int read_choices(FILE *pdata, QUESTION *q)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < q->n_choices; i++)
    {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pData) == 0 ||
            (q->choices[i] = dupString(choices)) == 0)
            return EOF;
    }
    return 0;
}

int parseQuestion(FILE *pData, int qnum, QUESTION *q)
{
    printf("******** Question: %d ********\n", num);
    *q = (QUESTION){ NULL, NULL, 0, NULL };

    if (read_info(pData, &q->question) == EOF ||
        read_number(pData, &q->n_choices) == EOF ||
        (q->choices = calloc(q->n_choices, sizeof(char *))) == 0 ||
        read_choices(pData, q) == EOF ||
        read_info(pData, &q->correct_answer) == EOF)
    {
        free_choices(q);
        return EOF;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could have `read_choices()` call `read_info()` iteratively instead of implementing `read_info()` inside `read_choices()`.  There's usually room for improvement in any code.

Comment: Great, I understand the logic.

Now with the implementation. At the moment I have parseQuestion returning a struct. I then take that struct and pass it to an ask() function which does what you'd think it would, returning 0, 1, 2 based on users choice.

Would I then need to write another function that would set up the QUESTION struct that's being passed to parseQuestion? Since that was its original purpose.

Comment: Instead of using a local `QUESTION question;` variable inside the `parseQuestion()` function, and `question.data_item = …;` to assign values to parts of the structure, you'd have a `QUESTION *question` argument to the function, and you'd use `question->data_item = …;` to  assign values to parts of the structure.  Other than that, and including the prompt based on the question number, it would remain largely unchanged.  IIRC, you have a data structure which has the text of the question, a number of alternatives, the list of alternatives, and the correct answer.

Comment: Looking at your `parseQuestion()` function, you'll need to check each and every `fgets()` function to ensure you don't get an unexpected EOF or other error.  You should also validate that the number of choices is in range (presumably 2..N for a smallish, probably single-digit, value of N).  Validating input is necessary; there'll always be someone who can't read the instructions on the screen or misformats the data in the file or ...  If you've got C99 or C11, you can write `*question = (QUESTION){NULL, 0, NULL, NULL};` to set the structure to a known state.  That's a compound literal.

Comment: That's fantastic Jonathan thank you for the help, I'll try and implement that now.

Comment: I'm having some issues. You have parseQuestion as a function returning an int, which I assume is necessary for EOF to be returned. However, it is then unable to return q which is a struct.

Comment: Bah! My bad; that's meant to be zero. However, I'll comment in my defence that I can't test the code because you didn't provide an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two different names for basically the same thing.

Comment: hey Jonathan I've posted up the code needed to run the program (some functions omitted). Check my edit to see what's going on now. And no issues on the zero, I should have realized that myself!

Comment: I remembered some of that code from a question yesterday.  You'll need to upgrade `free_choices()` to `free_question()` which should also release the memory for the question and the correct answer.  It might also set the various pointers to null and the count to zero so that if called twice in a row on the same structure, no damage would be done.

Comment: I appreciate the help, sorry to bug you like this but I'm learning a lot. I updated the free_choices method to free_question, you can see it above. However I'm getting the same problem. It starts at Question 2. I just added some more questions into the data file, and it starts again at Question 2 then when it moves to the next one, the fields are blank and I get a Segmentation 11 fault.

Comment: You call `parseQuestion()` to parse the first question, then `makeQuestion()` to parse the second question, and you only display the second question.

Comment: I thought `parseQuestion()` was just a function to test for the EOF, which we used as a condition in our while loop. So `while (there is another question) => makeQuestion() => ask()`

Comment: Obviously you're right because it's not working, I just don't understand the logic here.

Comment: No; under the revised scheme, `parseQuestion()` reads an entire question — subsuming the role of `makeQuestion()`. It needs to include a prompt.

Comment: I find it rather too easy to pass the quiz, but apart from that, it works.

Comment: The quiz should ask how to write a multiple choice quiz program in C :)